# Could a hybrid data model, like using JSON in fields, allow us to eliminate the need for EAV within something like magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, eav, json

I was reading about **EAV**, and what options are available to avoid the pain caused by it, and stumbled upon using **JSON** in fields.

This mariadb feature [page](https://mariadb.com/database-topics/semi-structured-data/) shows an example like,

```
SELECT name,
   JSON_VALUE(attr, "$.email.personal") AS email,
   JSON_VALUE(attr, "$.social.twitter") AS twitter,
   JSON_VALUE(attr, "$.interests[0]") AS favorite_interest
FROM   tbl_user_profiles
WHERE  user_id = "sjohnson";
```

The **JSON** is the part that would be a problem, if it was defined in a relational **table's schema**.  Is this really as viable as it looks at first glance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can.

But because it is a huge backward incompatible change it cannot be implemented in core in the nearest future

Also if you decide to switch to schema less data it is better to switch to document database like MangoDB

Comment: MongoDB would be a mistake IMO, for a few solid reasons.  First it doesn't provide a standardized query language, it also doesn't fit the requirements as well, because almost all of the data in Magento 2 really is relational. Only the additional attributes don't fit well in a relational model.  The cost of not using a relational model means querying becomes has to be more complex,  and push more work to the application layer, which is already required for the EAVs.